# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE en variable string con streamDownload, en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Hola tengo una función en streamdownload que genera un archivo tipo  tsv y lo descarga. Si lo declaro mediante **echo** como un **simple string** NO tengo problema y se descarga, si el **echo** lo que imprime es una variable tipo **string,array o el que sea** no se descarga el archivo, y me salta el error ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

Código

```
  $contenido="Contenido archivo";

  return response()->streamDownload(function () {

     echo $contenido;

 }, 'users.tsv');
```

Comment: Supongo que puede ser porque la variable $contenido está en otro ámbito cuando la defines y cuando la quieres usar. Prueba pasarle la variable a tu función anónima con use($variable) `->streamDownload(function () use ($contenido) {

     echo $contenido;

 }, 'users.tsv');`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias otra vez, eres como un steve jobs del laravel, no se de la de veces que me has salvado ya jajaja, una cuestion mas, para poder usarlo con una variable array simplemente deberia pasarle de otra manera que no sea use o ahi ya entro con los bucles?

Comment: Jaja, no creo que me haga millonario con laravel, como lo hizo jobs con apple. No entendí lo del array... Si quieres usar el valor de una variable del ambiente "padre" en una función anónima, se la pasas con `use`, sea ese valor un string o un array, o cualquier otro. Puedes leer más [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php). Pero no sé que harías con un array y bucles en el callback de `streamDownload`

Comment: pues básicamente quiero recoger todos los elementos de un array e imprimirlos como en el ejemplo de arriba, pero imagino  que para eso necesitaría el uso de algún tipo de bucle o callback como  has dicho tu.

Comment: Si en el array tienes strings, puedes usar [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) y tendrás un string al cual puedes imprimir con echo. Algo así: `->streamDownload(function () use ($array) { echo implode(", ", $array); }, 'users.tsv');`